# How to get data from a MySQL database and insert it into text

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a website of mine- it's a shop for different items (it's also my first website). I just got done with the HTML/CSS part of the website but I want to make it more dynamic and easier to edit without having to change multiple pages at once. One way I figured I could do this and also make it easier to implement a website search is by having the names and prices of the items in a database and having PHP code retrieve the name and price and insert it underneath the image of the item. Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how to go about this. I've tried looking for other people with similar questions but none of them seem to be specifically what I'm looking for. I'll put my PHP code below and then I'll put some html code that shows where I want to put the information.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "testpw";
$dbname = "testdb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error) {
}
$sql = "SELECT id, name, price FROM items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo " " .$row["id"]. " " .$row["name"]. " " .$row["price"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

So that's the PHP code that I use to get the information for each item. The problem though is that it gets the information for every item and displays it at once. I want the code to check for the ID of the item and then retrieve the stats about it and display them. This means if I want to rearrange items in the shop I only have to change the ID- which makes it much much easier for me to manipulate the shop and the items in it. Below is the HTML code for the items.

```
<div id="images">
<figure>
    <img class="gunimage" id="(THIS IS THE ID USED TO GET THE INFO)" src="idk.png" width="225" height="190" alt="">
    <figcaption><h3>Name: (INSERT NAME HERE USING PHP) </h3></figcaption>
    <figcaption><h5>Price: (INSERT OTHER PRICE HERE)/month</h5></figcaption>
    <figcaption><div id="tfbutton5"><form action="buy.html"><input   type="submit" value="Rent" class="tfbutton5"></form></figcaption>
</div>
</figure>
</div>
```

I labeled where I want the info to go, and I want to have the ID thing so the PHP code knows what item it is. I know both codes work separately, as I've tested both of them many times. Sorry if my question is really long, I wanted to make it as specific as possible so it's clear what my problem is. Please excuse if my code requires a lot of changes to make applicable in the situation I'm describing, as I only could figure out how to make something that lists out the info for every item. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)

Comment: Where would I add that in my code to only get information for an item with that set ID?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT id, name, price FROM items WHERE ID='the_item_id'";` If you want also the stats for the item, the query is more complex, since it involve at least one JOIN, but this depends on your database structure

Comment: Thanks! But that was half my question, how would I make it a function and then call that function in the middle of the HTML code?

Comment: Like is there anyways to make this PHP code a function that I can put in between the <figcaptions> to put the name of the item in the database with that ID? The ID would be designated in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do something more you could put in a file called 
'connection.php' or something more descriptive

```
  try { 
  $servername = 'localhost';
 $username = 'root';
 $password = 'testpw';
 $dbname = 'testdb';
 $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 } catch(Exception $e) {
   echo $e->error_list;
   exit;
 }
function execute_query($con, $query, $variables) {
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($variables);
return $stmt;
}
```

you could split these the top part in a connection.php while the function in a function.php file if you have more than one function.

```
include ('connection.php');
$id_number = $_GET['id'];
# !! NOTICE if grabbing | my understanding another page | 
// filter if grabbing from GLOBAL Variable $_GET 
$id = filter_var($id_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //take out 
if not grabbing from outside source.
$con = $db;
try {
   $query = 'SELECT t.id as id , t.name as name, t.price as price
   FROM items as t
   WHERE t.id = :id';
$variables[':id'] = $id;
  $items = execute_query($con, $query, $variables);
}catch(mysqli_error_list $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="images"><!-- i am guessing you want it within this div-->
<?php if(isset($item)) { ?>
 <?php foreach ( $items as $item) { ?> 
 <figure>
      <img class="gunimage" id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"
 src="idk.png" width="225" height="190" alt="<?php echo $item['name']; 
?>">
  <figcaption><h3>Name: <?php echo $item['name']; ?> </h3>
 </figcaption>
  <figcaption><h5>Price: <?php echo $item['price']; ?> </h5>
 </figcaption>
  <figcaption>
  <!-- instead of a id tfbutton5 needs to be a class otherwise your
  going to have an issue here when it loops, you will have an error-->
  <div class="tfbutton5"><form action="buy.html"><input
    type="submit" value="Rent" class="tfbutton5"></form>
  <!--also, not sure why you have an Id and a class  named exactly 
 identical but it is bad practice. sorry do not do it. -->
   </figcaption>
     </div>
     </figure>
  <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you wanted an image source, you would need to enter that into a database and connect your Items table to an Image table with that table having say..rows id, image, and item-id. then use the item-id as a point between the item and the image